# Cannot use Serenity for testing on BrowserStack and Launch WebTest on local machine

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browserstack, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

```
me (Rahul change)
```

16:06 (less than a minute ago)

Hello All, 
I have my project setup which uses Serenity With Cucumber for Web Browser testing. My company now wants to execute the test cases on Cloud Browsers and I was trying out BrowserStack.

The issue that I am at is, I am unable to comprehend how to to manage the driver to connect to the Remote Web Driver to execute tests on BrowserStack vs run them on the local machine (developing my test cases)

I used the [github](https://github.com/browserstack/serenity-browserstack) from BrowserStack but thats specifically designed to certain only certain test cases and cannot use it to execute it on Cloud vs Local machine.
Does anyone have a repo somewhere which can show how to manage this.

Regards,

Comment: can you create a sample repo with minimal code and share a link to the GitHub repo?

Comment: Sure, its [here](https://github.com/rahulkulkarniyahoo/serenity-browserstacktest)